# Why turn header off in curl?

Tags: php, curl

In quite a few curl examples people use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

What is the benefit of doing this?

I managed to display an image and I want to know what options I should put on/off and why.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1); // use?
curl_setopt($curlGetToken, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip'); // does it slow down MY server
```

Comment: Good question... CURLOPT_HEADER defaults to `false` to begin with, so other than for clarity, I don't know why you would set it to `false` explicitly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When CURLOPT_HEADER is set to 0 the only effect is that header info from the response is excluded from the output.  So if you don't need it that's a few less KBs that curl will return to you.

Comment: And can you tell me more about the other two? Will it be useful to enable them when loading a picture?

Comment: All CURL options descriptions are available here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php.  It looks like CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER is used to return the actual binary data when a url redirects (useful for images).  CURLOPT_ENCODING only tells the server what types of encoding it will accept.  So either way the data will only be decoded if needed.  But by giving CURLOPT_ENCODING a value you are limiting your call to only accept one type of encoding.

Answer (score 5):

As per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), it controls whether the response header(s) will be returned alongside the response body. Generally, if you only care about the response body, you want this disabled (which is the default value, `0`).

Answer (score 0):

E.g. when you trying to get some JSON stuff with the curl call you can easily do this:

```
$decodedData = json_decode($curlResult, true);
```

`$decodedData` is now an array.

If the headers are contained in `$curlResult` those have to be removed first (possibly with a reg exp).